# Implementing "side effects" in Express routes?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm looking for some advice on how to achieve something the "proper" way in Express.

When routes on my API are hit, I need to send a bunch of "side-effect" data to all clients via a websocket. All the websocket stuff is done and working, my question is mostly conceptual. So, for example, a POST is made to /message, after the route controller has handled the request and sent a response, I need to send some updated data regarding other data models via websocket to all clients.

I could, of course, just send the WS message from the route controller, but that feels haphazard and unstructured. I'm sure there must be a "proper" way to do it! I did wonder about creating a middleware that runs after the route controller that either examines the request and sends the appropriate updates, or takes something passed from the route controller and uses that to determine what to send. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Middleware installed after a route controller (which you may not realize is actually itself a middleware) will not execute. Well, you can call `next()` in your route controller to force it to execute but that is normally reserved for error handling

Comment: This is a pretty common use case for Redis. Your controller would send a message to some worker application through Redis. That worker would take care of that separately. If your architecture has to just be one Node app, then your controller will have to take care of that somehow. That's what controllers are for: to control the sequence that occurs when your route receives a valid request.